# If "a1" contains "multiple, strings, here" show "my-text" but if "a1" contains "other, strings, here" show "different-text" but if

Tags: excel

So essentially whats going on is this. I have a list of products in column A.

I want to be able to assign values in column B based on if A1 contains X.

Here are some examples:

If A1 contains Angry Orchard, Redds, or Strongbow, then B1 should say: Apple Beer.

BUT if A1 contains Lite or Light then B1 should say: Light Beers.

BUT If A1 contains Fireball, Absolute Vodka, or Malibu, then B1 should say: Liquor.

This could go on hundreds of times. So I'm thinking I'd go over my nested limit.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Make a table of the keywords and the desired result. Then use an index match as an array formula.

Comment: Could you go more in depth?

Comment: I can put the keywords in a table, but if you can give me an example of the array formula that'd be terrific.